# Error with Android Studio and dart SDK versioning

Tags: android, flutter, dart

So i was learning flutter and didnt have a problem with it, until i tried to clone a project from github, because when i went into the pubspec.yaml and tried to click pub get, i got this error:
The current Dart SDK version is 2.5.0.

Because horta requires SDK version >=2.6.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1)
Process finished with exit code 1

But then i checked my dart and flutter versions:

Running flutter --version: Tools • Dart 2.9.0 (build 2.9.0-3.0.dev 94178e920e)

Running dart --version: Dart VM version: 2.7.2 (Mon Mar 23 22:11:27 2020 +0100) on "windows_x64",

What could i do to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Flutter uses dart sdk which is located in flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin

In your case which is 2.9.0 and when you run dart --version which gives you 2.7.2 is a separate dark sdk in your system . Flutter will only  use the 2.9.0 one .

But your current dart sdk shouldn't be 2.5.0 .
Can you check the (environment : ) in your pubspec.yaml

You can run the command "flutter clean" and see if it helps

Answer (score 0):

Something similar happened to me, my error was that I had wrong path for flutter/bin folder. go to: edit system environment variables> environment variables> in system variables choose 'path' and click on edit, make sure that inside all the paths that are there is the path to the flutter bin folder, if it is incorrect change it, if it does not exist add it, then accept in all open windows to save changes [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qmFL.png)